# How to remove AegisP.sys

Tags: windows-xp, service

When I boot my laptop, I get the following event in the error log...

I cannot tell which service is trying to use the aegisp.sys file or generating this event.  Can anyone shed some light?  Google is not very helpful with this issue ;)

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Service Control Manager
Event Category: None
Event ID:   7000
Date:       8/20/2010
Time:       10:50:03 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   XXX
Description:
The AEGIS Protocol (IEEE 802.1x) v3.6.0.0 service failed to start due to the following error: 
The system cannot find the file specified. 

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it *looks* like this was installed by WireShark.  I uninstalled Wireshark, and the file went away, and more importantly, no more BSOD.